# Duende Identity server(v6) to Identity server5

Tags: c#, angular, duende-identity-server, identityserver5

We have our old Identity server5 which is used for our website for Authentication purposes. We are building another Duende Identity server for our new Mobile App(Angular). Can we call our Old Identity server from our new one using PKCE flow?

Comment: You don't need to setup another Identity Server, you can use the same server for website and mobile app. Just need to configure different clients